# How to set primary key with auto increment in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, primary-key

How to set primary key with auto increment in MongoDB ?

Normally MongoDB generates ObjectID. I wanna use my own auto increment primary key like MySQL.

Examples would be appreciated :)

Comment: First Google result: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36124413/2837412

Answer (score 9):

I blogged about this here:
http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/mongodb-incremental-ids/

I also started a int id generator for the C# driver:
https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/MongDBIntIdGenerator

However, incrementing ID's won't scale effectively.

Comment: Why incrementing IDs won't scale effectively?

Comment: Because each node would have to constantly know the "latest" id... Twitter 'snowflake' provides a solution to this, however. Also, read this - https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/

Answer (score 6):

```
$db->execute("return db.getCollection('autoInccollection').findAndModify({
                        query: { collection: '$colle' },
                        update: { '$inc': { primaryKey: 1 } },new: true
                            })");
```

$colle means which collection you need to create the Auto increment key.