# Incremental field to existing collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing around 100k documents. I want to add an auto incrementing "custom_id" field to my documents, and keep adding my documents by incrementing that field from now on.

What's the best approach for this? I've seen some examples in the official document (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) however they're only for adding new documents, not for updating an existing collection.

Example code I created based on the link above to increment my counter:

```
function incrementAndGetNext(counter, callback) {
    counters.findAndModify({
        name: counter
    }, [["_id", 1]], {
        $inc: {
            "count": 1
        }
    }, {
        "new": true
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        callback(doc.value);
    })
}
```

On the above code `counters` is `db.counters` collection and I have this document there:

```
{_id:"...",name:"post",count:"0"}
```

Would love to know.

Thank you.

P.S. I'm using native mongojs driver for js

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement an auto-incrementing primary ID in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356993/how-do-you-implement-an-auto-incrementing-primary-id-in-mongodb)

Comment: And I also just gave this link two questions ago: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Comment: @BlakesSeven that link is the one I mentioned above, it does not work when frequently adding documents.

Comment: @Zettam : Why would you ever need an "Incremental field"? Your question is not clear enough, you've seen "some examples", we're not here to guess what the examples are, we're not here to guess if there are weakness in examples we know nothing about, and we're not here to guess if you believe by mistake that an example is bad and then to guess what to explain. Please rewrite your question if you need help. (I have some ideas in my head, but I won't write about it if I'm not sure about what your question is...)

Comment: the code I am trying is linked. I mentioned the issue, when adding too many documents, it breaks. You can try.

Comment: @Zettam: ok you added a link just now, thanks!

Comment: @Mia So which "driver" are you using here, or is this just the shell? Where is the generate incremental id function? Nothing here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven native mongodb for js

Comment: @BlakesSeven yes, native js driver - with nodejs. This is the code I'm using. It works, but only for single additions.

If this is not -even- for nodejs then I'm missing something out entirely.

Comment: This is not valid code for what you are claiming you are using. I assume you have no code at all and are just asking someone to write things for you. My vote is in.

Comment: I've added an answer using the other approach of your link. Hope it may help you. Else, explanation about how "the method does not work" would help to provide answers.

Comment: @BlakesSeven modified my post to show more

Answer (score 1):

Well, [using the link you mentionned](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), I'd rather use the [counters collection approach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#use-counters-collection).

The counters collections approach has some drawbacks including :

- It always generates multiples request (two): one to get the sequence number, another to do the insertion using the id you got via the sequence,
- If you are using sharding features of mongodb, a document responsible for storing a counter state may be used a lot, and each time it will reach the same server.

However it should be appropriate for most uses.

The approach you mentionned (["the optimistic loop"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#optimistic-loop)) should not break IMO, and I don't guess why you have a problem with it. However I'd not recommend it. What happens if you execute the code on multiple mongo clients, if one has a lot of latency and others keep taking IDs? I'd not like to encounter this kind of problem... Furthermore, there are at least two request per successful operation, but no maximum of retries before a success...

Comment: Thank you for the great insight. However I could not get my head around using the same loop to go through all of my existing documents to add an incremental field to them. Any ideas would be appreciated. For a new collection it works perfectly fine.