# Why doesn't save method work inside find method callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get the last inserted _id in the MongoDB and then insert a new document that has incremented _id from the last one and save it. 
I Write this code it just gets the last _id but it doesn't save the document

```
Product.find({}, function(err , result)
    {
           if(!err)
           {
               result.forEach((p)=>{
                   count = p._id;
               });
               var product = new Product();
               product._id = count++;
               product.Name  = req.body.Name;
               product.Price = req.body.Price;
               product.Quantity = req.body.Quantity; 
               product.Imgsrc = req.body.Imgsrc;
               product.Cat_id = req.body.Cat_id;
               product.save((err, result)=>
               {
                    if(!err)
                    console.log(result);
               });
          }
     }
```

my module is

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProductSchema = new  mongoose.Schema({

    _id : {type : Number } , 
    Name : {type : String} , 
    Price : {type :Number} ,
    Quantity  : {type : Number} , 
    Imgsrc : {type : String} , 
    Cat_id :   { type: Number , ref : 'Categorys' } 
});


var product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema, "Product")

module.exports = product;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you show us the model for product?

Comment: What is the erro being thrown? Using _id like you do in this code can lead to _id collision in an real application, or an erro if you are using the native _id. Try to console.log the err

Comment: I add my module to the question above and when I run it doesn't  appear any error it doesn't save the document

Comment: I think it is a valid advice to use console.log(err), the way your code is built it will not log any errors if there are any.

Comment: Please provide the error from your console or terminal. Quite a few things could be causing this issue.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement an identity int for _id? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356993/how-do-you-implement-an-auto-incrementing-primary-id-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should try re-writing this piece of code like this:

```
Product.find({}, {sort: {_id: -1}, limit: 1}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
         console.log(err)
    }

    var count = result[0]._id;
    var product = new Product({
         product._id: ++count,
         ...req.body
    });

    product.save(err => console.log(err));
  });
```

If I'm not mistaken .save() method do not return the saved document, but even if it does, your code do not stop if there is any errors on saving because you
assume "!err" to do "you stuff". JavaScript will not care if some error occurs and you do not throw it, so you must log it to see if there is any.