# How can I make a number id pattern 1, 2, 3, 4 in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How do I make a pattern like this? I can't code that because i'm new to this.

This is my code

```
array = 1,2,3,4,5

const note = new notedModel ({
      _id: array,
      note: args[1],

});
```

Also using other modules if you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it could be helpful

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

const notes = array.map(element => new notedModel({
    _id: element,
    note: args[1], // or maybe args[element] if you need to select arg by array's element 
}));
```

---

P.S. You could read answers here to be careful with ids: [How do you implement an auto-incrementing primary ID in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356993/how-do-you-implement-an-auto-incrementing-primary-id-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
class NotedModel{
  constructor(id, arg){
    this._id = id
    this._note = arg
  }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var note = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  note.push(new NotedModel(arr[i], i));
}

console.log(note);
```