# How do I do a number ID pattern and check the ID's if they're exists or not in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I will reask this: [How can I make a number id pattern 1, 2, 3, 4 in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547933/how-can-i-make-a-number-id-pattern-1-2-3-4-in-mongoose), I poorly explained in that post. So I want to do a number pattern like `1,2,3,4,5` but infinitely. And then how to repeat the `findbyID` function?
I don't know how to repeat the function that if the ID **1** exists then the ID **2** and then ID **3** and then it goes on infinitely. 
Could somebody help me with this?

This is my code: (Sorry if my English is bad, I'm from another country.)

```js
const note = new noteModel ({
    _id: (here infinite number),
    note: 
    User:
    UserId:
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot assign id yourself like 1,2,3....infinity. Because `Mongoose` automatically generates a unique `ObjectID`, you cannot manipulate it. So, if you want to find all the data in a particular model you could just use one of these (**`User` is a model**):

```js
User.find({}); 
User.findAll();
User.find();
```

You could also check out the `Mongoose` docs and find various methods too. 
You don't have to put a loop on the `User.findbyID()` function to access all the data there are various methods

Comment: I meant like it should 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and then it goes on and i want the check the id's if exist or not

Comment: man you have to tell me more clearly what you are trying to achieve here? I don't get it what is it you are asking show me your code and the goal you are trying to achieve with it